# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array laravel.. for graphic

Tags: laravel

I hope someone can help me. I came across a very complex Laravel query and I don't know how to get out of it. My problem is that in the database I would like to group a series of columns so that the results of these groups are unique because they are repeated and select data from other columns belonging to these groups e.g. warehouse column is repeated 3 times I would like it to be displayed once, listing all the warehouse audit dates in another column and the results of these dates in another column. I wrote like this but I don't get the result. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong, thank you very much.. I would like to get some kind of graph..[image]
[image]

```
$area = DB::table('esiti_audit')->select([
    'master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea',
    'data_audit', 'esito'
  ])
  ->where('employee', $name)
  ->orderByDesc('data_audit')
  ->get()->toArray();

$data = [];

foreach($area as $audit) {
  
  $areaKey = "{$audit['master_zone']}|{$audit['subarea']}|{$audit['microarea']}";

  $data[$areaKey][] = [
    'esito' => $audit['esito'],
    'data_audit' => $audit['data_audit']
  ];
}
```

Comment: did you try dumping `$audit`? My guess is this is not an array, but an object. In that case you just need to read it as an object `$audit->master_zone` instead of `$audit['master_zone']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the array syntax then you need to convert the collection items to array so please replace your below code to given code:

```
$area = DB::table('esiti_audit')->select([
    'master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea',
    'data_audit', 'esito'
    ])
    ->where('employee', $name)
    ->orderByDesc('data_audit')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

To

```
$area = DB::table('esiti_audit')->select([
    'master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea',
    'data_audit', 'esito'
    ])
    ->where('employee', $name)
    ->orderByDesc('data_audit')
    ->get();
$area = $area->map(function ($record) {
    return (array) $record;
})->toArray();
```